# Why can't we define the mapping cone as $M^\bullet\oplus L[1]^\bullet$?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Consider the short exact sequences of complexes on an abelian category

[image]

Let $\tilde{N}^\bullet$ be the direct sum $M^\bullet\oplus L[1]^\bullet$. I wonder why doesn't $\tilde{N}^\bullet$ has all the nice properties of the mapping cone $MC(\varphi^\bullet)$. (Of course, the only difference between them is the differential.)

I've verified that $\tilde{N}^\bullet$ is indeed a complex, that it has a natural morphism of complexes $\rho^\bullet:\tilde{N}^\bullet\to N^\bullet$ (given by composing the natural projection $\tilde{N}^\bullet\to M^\bullet$ with $\psi^\bullet$), and that it fits in the exact sequence

[image]

Another main feature of $MC(\varphi^\bullet)$ is that the morphism $MC(\varphi^\bullet)\to N^\bullet$ is a quasi-isomorphism. I think that this may be the problem here; perhaps $\rho^\bullet$ is not always a quasi-isomorphism.

**I would love to understand why it may not be a quasi-isomorphism and, if possible, to find some concrete examples.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a concrete example : (by the way, this is a very common example in homological algebra, and you can very often check your assertions with it).

Consider the short exact sequence
$$ 0 \longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\overset{\times 2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z/2Z}\longrightarrow 0$$
where every group is considered as a complex concentrated in degree 0.

Then the mapping cone of the map $\times 2$ is given by the complex $...\longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\overset{\times 2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow 0\longrightarrow ...$ where the $\mathbb{Z}$ are concentrated in degree -1 and 0. Obviously the cohomology of this complex is $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ in degree 0 and 0 otherwise so this is thus quasi-isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$.

On the other hand, the direct sum is the complex $...\longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\overset{0}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow 0\longrightarrow ...$ and its cohomology is given by $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree -1 and 0. So this is not quasi-isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$.